# start and pause not working in youtube

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I want to start and pause the video as in the reference link 
  `.`    [reference link](http://jsfiddle.net/8R5y6/)

I tried to create the same in another fiddle in
     [my sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcczzcu6/)

What I did wrong here? Do I need to add any library here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hi i have updated that below is the link.. you have to upload script in head. In js fiddle there is option load type there ,select head section

   https://jsfiddle.net/jcczzcu6/4/
```

Comment: start,stop and play action not working in your fiddle

Comment: can you do try in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41275693/stop-youtube-video-in-jquery?noredirect=1#comment69753617_41275693)